# Checkbox event is always undefined. React Hook Form controller not updating state immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm using React Hook Form. I have a checkbox wrapped in Controller.

1. First problem is that onChange event always gives undefined
2. Second problem - before the first appeared (unfortunately I don't know after which change) it managed to work but I didn't know how to get current form state - it was updated only after resetting or submitting the form. As you can see I have added a validation rule to the checkbox. I need to enable submit button based on that checkbox so I need to have a current formState immediately.

```
<Controller
                        render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
                            <Checkbox
                                // checked={value}
                                onChange={(e) => {
                                    console.log(e.value);
                                    onChange(e.value);
                                   // this print undefined                                
                                }}
                            >
                                Some text
                            </Checkbox>)}
                        control={control} // this changes nothing
                        defaultValue={false} // I've tried also with default values passed to the FormProvider
                        name='checkbox'
                        rules={{
                            validate: (value: boolean) => value
                        }} />
```

Comment: write `e.target.checked` like `onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.checked)}` instead of `e.value`. (*looks like you are using MUI for the Checkbox)

Comment: I'm using something similar to MUI and I've checked that e.value is what I need.

In other cases when I'm using this checkbox onChange={onChange} is working

Comment: can you put this in codesandbox? and share url.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out that problem is that this checkbox needs string as a value, not a boolean

```
    <Controller
                        control={control}
                        render={({ field }) => (
                            <Checkbox {...field}
                                checked={field.value}
                                value={field.value as unknown as string}
                            >Text
                            </Checkbox>)}
                        defaultValue={false}
                        name='checkbox'
                        rules={{
                            validate: (value: boolean) => value
                        }} />
```

Comment: The value do not update of the checkbox.